# Java signed applet certificate revoked only on mac OSX10.7 (Lion)

Tags: java, macos, applet, certificate, osx-lion

I have a signed applet that works fine on windows, Mac <= 10.6, and linux. However, on OSX lion, the signing certificate is revoked. Here is the security debug info from the java console:

```
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading Root CA certificates from from keychain
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from from keychain
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: jpicertstore.cert.getkeystore
security: No timestamping info available
security: Cannot find jurisdiction list file
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: PC Operating Center
security: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.thawte.com/ThawteCodeSigningCA.crl]
]]

security: Thawte Code Signing CA
security: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.thawte.com/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl]
]]

security: Use CRL setting from certificate
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: PC Operating Center
security: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.thawte.com]
]

security: This certificate does not have AIA extension
security: Use OCSP setting from certificate
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://crl.thawte.com/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl, version: null]
network: Connecting http://crl.thawte.com/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://crl.thawte.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://crl.thawte.com/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl
    Content-Length: 181,278
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://crl.thawte.com/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl to File /Users/koutbo6/Library/Caches/Java/cache/6.0/38/2fb889a6-30a08967-temp
network: Connecting http://ocsp.thawte.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://ocsp.thawte.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: CleanupThread used 990300 us
network: Connecting http://ocsp.thawte.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://ocsp.thawte.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: This certificate has been revoked
Ignored exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate has been revoked
```

Would appreciate any tips on how to get the signed applet to work on Lion.

UPDATE:

here is the serial number for the cert: 28 A9 29 38 64 0D FC 5D 7D 1D 05 CE 7F 1D 81 E0

I noticed the following, on snow leopard, if I go to advanced settings of java preferences and enable "Check certificates for revocation using CRL" I get the same issue as in lion.

I check lion java preferences and the option was disabled yet the certificate is still revoked

On snow leopard, I disabled the option again and everything works fine

Comment: Do you know why your certificate has been revoked? That's not dependent on the OS; the other OSes just must not be checking for CRLs.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, would appreciate any pointers on how to find out the cause. But as I said, this behavior is observed only on Lion, the signed applet works fine on snow leopard and the certificate is not revoked

Comment: Do you have a copy of the certificate? Or at least the serial-number?

Comment: Could you check if the chains are the same on each machine? Maybe a CA certificate was updated?

Comment: Wait a second, has OCSP been switched on on the other machines? Are you sure that OCSP service reacts correctly?

Comment: Would be great if you could make a copy of the certificate available (of course not the key or anything) - that way we could see whether OCSP really says the certificate is revoked. That's my bet currently - Lion uses OCSP whereas it's turned off by default on the other machines.

Comment: Your certificate is revoked. Your question should be, "Why doesn't it work correctly except on Lion?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Java uses the global preference settings in the "Keychain Access" application?
This application can be found under Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.

Default settings indicate:

```
Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP): Best attempt
Certificate Revocation List (CSP): Best attempt
Priority: OCSP
```

You could verify if the application accepts your certificate if you (temporarily) turn OCSP and CRL off.

In any case, you should probably not be using a revoked certificate... :-)

Comment: BTW: Does the code actually fail, or do you just see the problem in the Java Console? The text from the console says "Ignored exception: ...".

Comment: No idea why the certificate is revoked, and yes I see the text from the java console. While I personally wasnt able to get this to work, some have reported that turning off CSP from keychain got their app to work. The funny thing is, apple support managed to use the app without issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it on a non-lion machine that has never run your applet before? Maybe the other machines that you tested with already trust your applet.

Comment: yep ... tested new installations and it works perfectly on window/linux/mac ... the problem we're observing is only on lion