# The digital signature is not trusted. Java will not allow any access to this application

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start, sign, osx-mountain-lion

I have a Java Web Start application, which I've tested on Windows 7, Linux and Mac OS X 10.7 (works fine on all).

On Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion the following error occurs, with no option to choose "Allow".

The error looks like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sXoO.png]

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Who signed this Java Web Start application using what key?

Comment: [Check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868628/java-signed-applet-certificate-revoked-only-on-mac-osx10-7-lion).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just found a solution: Go into System prefs -> security and privacy, and check the box that allows applications to be downloaded from anywhere (you might have to click the lock to make changes to this)

Comment: Anything which depends on disabling the OS' default security is not a solution!

Comment: It's a solution for the problem that the OS's supposed security mechanism causes. I suppose it depends on the certificate that was used to sign the application, but in my case, selecting the intermediate option, allowing "Mac App Store and identified developers" works as well.

Comment: for android screencast, at least, the certificate is expired - we are left with abandoning all security; irritating as it is

Comment: This is a per-user work-around for the issue. It would be great to have a developer/publisher solution to get Java Web Start on 10.7+ trusted by the Mac

Answer (score 3):

This is because of a new feature in Mountain Lion known as '**Gatekeeper**'. Following is a brief description:

**Choose where apps are installed from:**
Gatekeeper gives you three security options for downloading and installing apps for your Mac. You can download and install apps from anywhere, with the same protection that OS X Lion provides. For maximum security, choose to allow only apps from the Mac App Store to be installed. Or download and install apps from the Mac App Store and apps that have been signed with a Developer ID.

**Gatekeeper alert:**
Mountain Lion alerts you if you download and try to install an application from a developer who does not have a Developer ID.

**Manual override:**
If you receive an alert that an app is from an unidentified developer, you can still choose to install it. Control-click the installer or the application icon to reveal a contextual menu. Choose Open and you’ll see a dialog that allows you to install the application.

Comment: That manual override does not seem to work for Java web start applications, at least on 10.8.2.

Comment: The answer is not really helpful solving the issue. Anyway, the actual description isn't wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I would also add that once the app is installed and you know it's working. You can revert the setting that you changed to set your mind at ease in terms of your OS X Security.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Click "Show details"

Tick the "Always trust "…"" which refers to the expired (or whatever) certificate involved

Click continue, and authorise the change in cert trust settings, "Update settings", which is added to your keychain

if "Allow" is still greyed out, relaunch

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going to command line and using the following

```
$ sudo installer -pkg /path/to/installer -target /
```

and viewing the output. If you receive an error about the installer being untrusted and you know the source is accurate and you want to install it anyway, then

```
$ sudo installer -pkg /path/to/installer -allowUntrusted -target /
```

This is an issue with MacOS 10.8 and older installers using a different code signing tool than what Mountain Lion likes. Or so I'm told.

Answer (score -2):

This has nothing to do with Gatekeeper. I have Java 7 (JRE build 1.7_09) and I do have this popup. I also allowed everything in Security. The site I use is for banking but please note mydlink does not work, either, nor does the Yahoo finance screen.
This is the same exact thing that I had experienced back in 2003 on my Jaguar back when the Java RE was completely outside. Now, Apple handed it back to Oracle and look what happened (not to mention the font resolution on the Java window.
it is not accessing the certificates (or lacking the signatures). Solution would be simple if anybody at Oracle could program for this platform. Appe had fixed it and now they pulled the rug from under us. Java is not the future but tell it to my bank...

Answer (score -2):

OK here is he fix , just set your clock to manual and take it back a couple of years, then install the program and set your date and clock back to auto
sorted